# create quarter transparent hole at right bottom on overlay UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

Hi i want to create a quarter transparent hole at right bottom on overlay UIView.

i am able to solve it using below code. But it does not look right as i am creating a rectangle outside the bond of view.

What i have tried:

```
@implementation PartialTransparentView

- (id)initWithBottomRightCornerRadiusForView:(UIView *)view   withRadius:(CGFloat)radius
{
[self commonInitWithRect:CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width - radius,  view.frame.size.height - radius, radius*2, radius*2)];
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5000, 5000)];//**it does not look right to me**
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.opaque = NO;
}
return self;
}

-(void)commonInitWithRect:(CGRect)rect{
    backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.75];
    rectToBeSurrounded = rect;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [backgroundColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);



        CGFloat x = rectToBeSurrounded.origin.x;
        CGFloat y = rectToBeSurrounded.origin.y;

        CGFloat width = rectToBeSurrounded.size.width;
        CGFloat height = rectToBeSurrounded.size.height;

        //create outer square
        CGFloat outerX = (x - width/2);
        CGFloat outerY = y - height/2;
        CGFloat outerWidth = 2*width;
        CGFloat outerHeight = outerWidth;
        //create outer square

        CGRect outerRect = CGRectMake(outerX, outerY, outerWidth, outerHeight);

        CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( outerRect, rect );

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        if( CGRectIntersectsRect( holeRectIntersection, rect ) )
        {
            CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
            CGContextClip(context);
            CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
            CGContextFillRect( context, holeRectIntersection);
        }
}
```

Now i am using above code as :

```
PartialTransparentView *transparentView = [[PartialTransparentView alloc] initWithBottomRightCornerRadiusForView:self.view withRadius:50];
[self.view addSubview:transparentView];
```

Result as expected:

[image: OUTPUT]

i know my solution will break if i have to acheive same thing but on top left of view.
**what i am looking for just provide center (x, y) and radius for circle and get desired results.**

Thanks
Basd on Mr.T

```
UIView *transparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [transparentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.75]];
    [self.view addSubview:transparentView];

    circleView *acircleView = [[circleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 60)];
    [acircleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [transparentView addSubview:acircleView];
```

and circleView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    //// Oval Drawing
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 60)];
    [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
}
```

**output:**
[image: dont get circle , instead i am getting square]

Comment: u need a a way to pass parameters to draw Rect method ? is that what u r asking ?

Comment: basically my drawRect is dependent on rectToBeSurrounded variable. As to create a circle i have to create a square. I am able to initialize/populate this var in commonInitWithRect

Comment: y dont u simply draw a circle with bezier path and move it  on the overlay according it your need ?

Comment: does it looks good 5000, 5000 for a view width height. what wrong i am doing so that i have to take it 5000, 5000. If i don't take 5000, 5000 result is not desired

Comment: let me provide one way to achieve your task

Comment: yes please. i am working on it with last two days. And very first time in core graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions is to add the transparent `view` as a separate `view` on your view controller. This can be either done on `storyboard`,so that you can set the background color and the `alpha` value to give the transparent effect!!!

Now create another `view` to make the circle and add it to transparent `view`, , and move this `view` on the transparent `view` according to your need!!!

Create the circle using `bezier path`:

**circleView.m**

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {
    //// Oval Drawing
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame), 60, 60)];
    [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
}
```

For testing purpose, I have created a circle view on my IB and created an outlet property in my view controller.

HEre is the screenshot.

[image]

Now to move the circle, I can simply change the frame of the circle `view`, wherever I need.

For example, If I want to move it to top left, I simply do:

```
-(void)moveCircleViewwithX:(float) x withY:(float) y{

    _cView.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, _cView.frame.size.width, _cView.frame.size.height);


}
```

The result will be:

[image]

**Update**

Put the following the drawRect method of transparentView:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect transparentPart = self.seeRect;           //this is the rect of the circle view
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx,transparentPart);  //make the circle shape
CGContextClip(ctx);
CGContextClearRect(ctx, transparentPart);
```

and in your view controller:

when you want to apply the mask i.e the transparent for both circle and for the transparent layer:

```
-(void)applyMask{

    [_cView setCircleColor:[UIColor clearColor]];   //circle view bezier path color
    [_cView setNeedsDisplay];
    [_tView setSeeRect:_cView.frame];    //set the transparency cut on transparency view
    [_tView setNeedsDisplay];


}
```

Once you do this, you will get the transparency view!!!

You can move the circle by simply calling

```
      [self moveCircleViewwithX:-30 withY:10];   //top left corner
```

and you can apply the transparency mask by simply calling:

```
      [self applyMask];
```

So, the final result after you call the `applyMask` method will be:

[image]

Comment: please have a look at my question, i am getting square. thanks for your cooperation

Comment: make sure your outlet size ? It should be 60x60

Comment: IF you want to increase the circle size, also increase it in the draw rect method

Comment: u can even do it without an outlet!!! I used outlet for easy way to explain!!!! You can add transparent view programmatically by adding a uiview and making its background color transparent

Comment: at last one thing how to make this circle transparent

Comment: r u plannig to move the circle all over the view or just to the four corners of the view ?

Comment: just one any of the four corner at a time

Comment: You can make the circle trasparent, but there is another view behind the circle which is transparent, if you make the circle tranparent, it will show its behind view!!!!  There should be a way to mask the layer, I will update my answer soon,!!!

Comment: @Alok, I will further improve the answer with the circle cut, till then you can use the asnwer!!!!

Comment: @Alok, I updated my answer, plz check it!!!! YOu can now move circle at any point , and make it transparent too!!!!