# How can i blur and focus on image in ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimageview

i want to blur Whole image and display circle or rectangle area on image.
with move the circle and rectangle on image.save the blur image without circle and rectangle.

[image: CIRCLE IMAGE:]

[image: RECTANGLE IMAGE:]

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create quarter transparent hole at right bottom on overlay UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924229/create-quarter-transparent-hole-at-right-bottom-on-overlay-uiview)

Comment: I am not familiar with this SDK, but it seems that you can apply a filter (blur) over a region of interest (outside the circle/rectangle). This will yield the desired image. You will display the image and draw the outline as an overlay, i.e. it will not perturb the underlying image.