# objective c - creating a transparent rectangle with visible border and transparent side in iOS camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

I am creating an app with a barcode scanner that uses iOS camera. And an additional requirement is to create a square/rectangular shape on the center that will serve as a detector, and make the outer part of it blur.

I was able to create a square inside the camera but I don't know how to blur the outer part of the square. Please look at the picture below. I would like to make the outer part of the red square to be blured/white with transparency.

Here's my code that created the square.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

CAShapeLayer *rectLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[rectLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(screenWidth/8, (screenHeight/9) * 3, (screenWidth/8) * 6, (screenHeight/9) * 4)] CGPath]];
[rectLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[rectLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:rectLayer];
```

I would really appreciate if someone can show some codes. I am not an iOS developer, I am just creating this as a plugin on my application. Thank you.

[image: My App now looks like this]

Comment: you need an overlay. Create a view with blur and then cut the rectangle part on the blur view.

Comment: can you show some codes? I know how to create the view and blur it but I dont know how to cut the rectangle part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924229/create-quarter-transparent-hole-at-right-bottom-on-overlay-uiview/33924675#33924675

Comment: I tried this out and the square part needs to be transparent. If I am going to use the suggested code, the background will be visible in the middle of the square.

Comment: yes you are right. That's what you asked for. Rectangular part needs to be visible! and the rest is blurred! Isn't is what you need ?